# Google Drive api permission limit

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using Google Drive API v3. I am having problem on permissions. How can I remove permission request limit?

I believe that Google Drive API v3 have limit on permission requests of 50 per day. Is there a way to remove it?

What I am doing is an application that will get all files on user's drive and share write permission with my email address.

Comment: You need to formulate a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hard limit of 50 permission request per day in the Google drive API.

This is not something you can change or request an extension for.